# Bash sourced files work properly after initial input into terminal

Tags: bash, 22.04, bashrc

I am messing with my bash setup, and I decided to move it to version control, I made a couple of changes, and moved the `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` to my dotfiles repo. This seems to have caused quite an unusual bug, it seems that my sourced files are working, but the visual change only applies after inputting something, example

this is right after opening the terminal

[image]

If I type anything into it, it works as expected

[image]

My `bashrc`

```bash
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
*i*) ;;
*) return ;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
        # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
        # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
        # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
        color_prompt=yes
    else
        color_prompt=
    fi
fi

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
    if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
        . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
    elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
        . /etc/bash_completion
    fi
fi
```

My `.bash_profile`

```bash
source ~/.bashrc
if [ -e ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    source ~/.bash_aliases >/dev/null 2>&1
fi
```

Most of the logic is inside te `.bash_aliases`

```bash
# Enable for debugging purposes, it logs every command ran in the terminal
# set -x
unalias -a
set -o vi

echo "Welcome to $(hostname)!"

# The theme we'll be using
. $HOME/.bash_theme

# Set up GOPATH and GIT_EDITOR
export CLUTTER_BACKEND=wayland
export XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland-egl
export QT_WAYLAND_FORCE_DPI=physical
export QT_WAYLAND_DISABLE_WINDOWDECORATION=1
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=sway
export XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=sway
export SDL_VIDEODRIVER=wayland
export _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1
export MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1
export MOZ_WEBRENDER=1

# Set up PATH
export PATH="$HOME/.amplify/bin:$PATH"
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$HOME/.local/.npm-global/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/.local/n/bin/:$HOME/.local/go/bin:$HOME/go/bin:$HOME/bin:$HOME/bin:$HOME/scripts:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/scripts
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
export GOPATH="$HOME/go"
PATH="$GOPATH/bin:$PATH"
. "$HOME/.cargo/env"

bind 'set show-mode-in-prompt on'
bind 'set vi-ins-mode-string "\1\e[1;32m\2+\1\e[0m\2 "'
bind 'set vi-cmd-mode-string "\1\e[1;32m\2:\1\e[0m\2 "'

# Set NVM_DIR and source the nvm and bash_completion scripts
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"

# Set up XDG_CONFIG_HOME and VIM
export XDG_CONFIG_HOME=$HOME/.config

# Source personal environment and files
PERSONAL=$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/personal/bash
for i in $(find -L $PERSONAL -type f); do
    . $i
done

COMMON=$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/common
for i in $(find -L $COMMON -type f); do
    . $i
done

# Set VISUAL and EDITOR
export EDITOR="nvim"
export GIT_EDITOR=$EDITOR

export menu="albert"

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/

bind 'set bell-style none'

# Temp fix for atuin https://github.com/atuinsh/atuin/issues/1012
eval "$(atuin init bash --disable-up-arrow)"

_atuin_fix_echo() {
    stty echo
    stty sane
}

if [[ -n "${BLE_VERSION-}" ]]; then
    blehook PRECMD-+=_atuin_fix_echo
else
    precmd_functions+=(_atuin_fix_echo)
fi
# end atuin

if [[ -f ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.github ]]; then
    eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.github
fi

# Have to install bash-preexec as well
[[ -e ~/.bash-preexec.sh ]] && source ~/.bash-preexec.sh

source ~/.config/broot/launcher/bash/br
source ~/.config/wezterm/wezterm.sh
eval "$(zoxide init bash)"
eval "$(starship init bash)"

[[ -e ~/.config/personal/bash/alias_personal ]] && \. ~/.config/personal/bash/alias_personal

[ "$(tty)" = "/dev/tty1" ] && exec sway
```

I often SSH into my machine, so this is the setup I landed on, I am pretty sure it's far from best practices but it worked relatively well prior to the changes I made today. Unfortunately I have no version control on the bashrc and the profile files so I have no idea what exactly caused the issue. My current knowledge does not give me any ideas as to what could be the culprit, its super weird.

I am on Ubuntu 22.04, Wayland, the exact dotfiles can be [found here](https://github.com/Nikola-Milovic/.dotfiles/tree/master/bash). I am using [`starship.rs`](https://starship.rs/) as my prompt. It all worked fine yesterday, prior to my changes, (the changes were minimal, I don't think I added anything, just removed some comments, I mustve removed something I thought wasn't important)

If I source without removing the output, eg

```bash
if [ -e ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    source ~/.bash_aliases #>/dev/null 2>&1
fi
```

I get the following output

`Welcome to nikola-B450M-DS3H!`

Which comes from the file that also inits my prompt and everything, meaning its being sourced correctly, but for some reason its not applied on the inital opening of the terminal. The weird part is, if I add `reset` or `clear` to the end of the `.bash_profile` in hopes of fixing the issue, it still stays, but if I manually type clear or reset, it works. So I am totally lost